# SQL Server High Availability Always On Cluster - Archiving Without Skipping Records

Tags: sql-server, high-availability

We have a High Availability Always On Group that is read and processed by a third party tool, originally we used the Primary Key to detect where we were up to in the tables but these can skip during failover and there is concern in the team that during failover a newer record can receive a lower Primary Key value and the record can be skipped in the archival process.

Clarification: Auto Incrementing Primary Keys can skip values during a server fail over, I believe this is due to identity reservation. The concern in the team is that in certain fail over situations, a record may be entered with an out of sequence primary key, that is, one server might create a record with a PK value and another server then creates a record with a PK value that is lower.

We then started using RowVersion for current record detection but this has had a large impact on query times, even with indexing set up.

What would be the standard approach to reading data sequentially in this sort of cluster.

Thanks

Comment: Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.

Comment: Please clarify: "can skip during failover and there is concern in the team that during failover a newer record can receive a lower Primary Key value and the record can be skipped in the archival process".

Comment: Clarification: Auto Incrementing Primary Keys can skip values during a server fail over, I believe this is due to identity reservation. The concern in the team is that in certain fail over situations, a record may be entered with an out of sequence primary key, that is, one server might create a record with a PK value and another server then creates a record with a PK value that is lower.